# bing maps v7 production URL

Tags: bing-maps

I applied on the site bingmaps ajax controll v7. I have before me the task: apply the production URL. Throughout the documentation used by the reference to the map: http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol... - this is URL for developers. 
Tell me if there is a some sort production URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Staging environment reference to the map control is:
http://staging.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2

The Production environment reference to the map control is:
http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.2

Comment: That article is not relevant - it describes how to implement token identification in Bing Maps v6.x, a process that was retired over a year ago - the OP is talking about using v7.x, which is a completely different SDK.

Answer (score 3):

The link in your original question has been truncated so it's a bit hard to see exactly what URL you are attempting to use, but the correct URL for the v7 AJAX map control is:

http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=7.0

Don't be misled by the fact there's a "dev" in the URL - this is the URL that you'd use for a production app. You might also find this page useful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427624.aspx